# making x0 and y0 start from center in jframe?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

Hi I was just wondering how I am able to make the x and y axis start from the center of the jframe without using `frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null)` because I want to be able to have the jframe follow my cursor, right now it is putting the jframe's top left corner to my cursor but i want it to be in the center.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite easy task

```
int newX=cursorX-frame.getWidth()/2;
int newY=cursorY-frame.getHeight()/2;
```

and than

```
frame.setLocation(newX,newY);
```

This will position your frame in a way that mouse cursor will be in the middle of it.

Comment: great! I got it to work as I want it to work, thanks!